# Vista and shoutcast compatibility

Tags: windows-vista

Is there anyone out there that knows why Vista and the Shoutcast encoder plugin for dj'ing with winamp just do not seem to get along? The moment I turn Shoutcast on, my CPU usage goes through the roof. With Vista, Shoutcast will not save all the settings and one has to remember to change them each time.

Comment: Try to separate the question from the rant, it would make it more clear.

Comment: It looks like there's no true question here. Shoutcast doesn't support Vista or Win7, only 98 - XP. Although it's interesting to see that they'll still support Windows 98 but not Vista. Judging from that alone, I wouldn't expect any quick results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running shoutcast as Administrator? (Right-click and "Run as Administrator").

Another thing to try is running it in Windows XP compatability mode. (Right-click the application, properties, Compatibility tab)